# Overlapping divs within a relative position div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have two divs overlapping. One with a background image, and one with just text to overlap the image on the bottom right. But I want to wrap each 'set' in a div (I want to use `section` if possible) so that I can space them apart easier (creating WordPress theme) since each set is put one after the other.

EDIT: I intentionally want the text to go below the image div. That's why I want to wrap them both so that the text on one doesn't overlap the next set.

ex [image]

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: inherit;
}

#article-txt {
  min-height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 70%;
  z-index: 25;
  bottom: -150px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 25px 25px 0 25px;
}

#article-img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="article-txt">
    text text
  </div>
  <div id="article-img" style="background-image:url('...');">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a **negative** bottom value means to go *further away* from the bottom that is downwards not upwards. When you use **positive values** from any direction, they `move to the center` and if negative they move away.

So, if you use `bottom;0px` then it will stay at the bottom of the image, if you use `positive value` with bottom say 50px, it will move *50px towards the center i.e upwards*.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: inherit;
  margin-bottom:170px;
}

#article-txt {
  min-height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 70%;
  z-index: 25;
  right: 0;
  bottom:-150px;
  padding: 25px 25px 0 25px;
}

#article-img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="article-img" style="background-image:url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x150');">
  </div>
  <div id="article-txt">
    text text
  </div>
</section>
RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF RANDOM STUFF
```

**Update:** No wrapping is going to solve that issue *if you're using position absolute*. It will overlap with the next content since the next content doesn't take the contents which are positioned absolute in consideration.

**What's the workaround?**

You can set the `margin-bottom of the <section>` to the negative bottom value of the text or more. So, if you're using bottom:-150px, you can set the section's margin bottom to 150px or more.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, But I intentionally want it to be offset below the bottom. That's why I want to wrap them both in a div, since that would overlap the set below it. I can't control whats in the text (so therefor the height)

Comment: @user3550879 But you want the text overlapped with the image anyways at the bottom?

Comment: I uploaded an mage of what I'm looking for. It overlaps the image it's with, but not the next set. it should only overlap the image above it at the bottom right

Comment: @user3550879 Updated.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working the way I'd desire. I figure if I could get the two divs to overlap, and then somehow wrap them then I could apply margins/padding to the outer wrapping to make sure they don't overlap

Comment: @user3550879 margin-bottom provides the same workaround without the need of additional containers.

Comment: margin bottom on the text div wouldn't affect the next set, and since I don't know how high the text will be, putting a margin bottom on the image/section div would be hard to set

Comment: @user3550879 It doesn't matter how high your text goes, since it will always lie just above -150px as set, it isn't the starting point, but the ending point. So, yeah margin-bottom will work fine, you can try it with varying heights.